# Connect to postgresql on windows

Tags: c++, postgresql

When I code some client for `postgresql` in `cpp` I always have a problem with this simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <libpq-fe.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

char pghost[] = "localhost";
char pgport[] = "5432";
char pgbase[] = "baza";
char pguser[] = "postgres";
char pgpass[] = "server";
char conninf[] = "host=localhost port=5432 database=postgres user=postgress password=server";

int main(){    
  PGconn *conn = PQsetdbLogin(pghost,pgport,NULL,NULL,pgbase,pguser,pgpass);

  if (PQstatus(conn) == CONNECTION_OK)
  {
    //if connected
    cout<<"Ok.\n";
  }
  else
  {  
    cout<<"ERROR: %s\n";
    PQfinish(conn);
    }
    return 0;
  }
}
```

I have an error output

```
C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\connect\connect.cpp|16|undefined reference to `PQsetdbLogin'|
```

and a lot of errors to other functions from the library.

What I'm doing wrong? How do I connect to this library on Windows correctly?

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/libpq-build.html):

```
testlibpq.o: In function `main':
testlibpq.o(.text+0x60): undefined reference to `PQsetdbLogin'
testlibpq.o(.text+0x71): undefined reference to `PQstatus'
testlibpq.o(.text+0xa4): undefined reference to `PQerrorMessage'

This means you forgot -lpq.
```

Try to pass the `-lpq` flag and see if those other errors you mention disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Your libpq-fe.h file contains the :
extern PGconn *PQsetdbLogin ??

Also check your libs. Probably it's a libq -linker which is missing  .

Try to include include/postgresql -L/lib -lpq  while you are building your project.